# Relation between pearson correlation p-value and two sample independent t-test

Tags: correlation, t-test

I have a list of binary labels (0 or 1) for a number of examples and the corresponding predicted probabilities for class 1. My first goal is to estimate pearson correlation between binary labels and predicted probabilities. My second goal is to perform a two-sample independent t-test between the probabilities assigned to positive vs negative labeled examples. The code is the following:

```
corr,p_value_pearson =  stats.pearsonr(labels, probs)
t-value, p_value_t_test = stats.ttest_ind(probs[labels == 1],probs[labels == 0])
```

My question is simple: In my experiments, I did not expect to see that p_value_pearson is equal to p_value_t_test (at least for a very high number of decimals). This happens with many different sets of probabilities, produced by different algorithms. So, computationally or mathematically speaking, should these two quantities be equal?

**Edit:**

I am adding a minimum example with some random data. As you can see, the two p-values are equal to a high number of decimals.

```
>>> labels = np.array([0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])
>>> probs = np.array([0.4,0.3,0.6,1,0.4,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.4,1]) 
>>> stats.pearsonr(labels,probs)
PearsonRResult(statistic=-0.242714156989133, pvalue=0.447193538615674)
>>> stats.ttest_ind(probs[labels==0],probs[labels==1])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=0.7911877721292354, pvalue=0.44719353861567435)
```

**Edit 2:**

As for the motivation, I am wondering whether I should pass the p_values as a single column (because they are equal) or two different columns in the results table of my report.

**Edit 3:**

The exact same results happen when I use point bi-linear correlation, which for two classes I assume is the same as pearson correlation.

Comment: There’s definitely a relationship between correlation and the two-sample t-test, as the t-test can be viewed as a regression on a group indicator variable. However, this seems to be screaming out XY problem. What are you doing to get these predicted probabilities? What is the greater context of your work? I can post or link to a more detailed answer about the relationship between correlation and the t-test, but it might address your attempted solution to solve your problem instead of your actual problem.